# C: issue with printing 2d array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, printf

I'm working on my C code, and got a problem with printing my 2d array. Instead of printing one string at the time, it prints the entire array from the asked point.

As an example, the input is, "Dog", "Cat", "Hat". Then it would print out:

```
DogCatHat
CatHat
Hat
```

This is what my code is suppsoed to do: It reads from a file. It creates an array of char arrays. Where each char array has 30 chars in them, read from file one char at the time. Then it prints out one char array per line.

This is what the code looks like:

```
char fname[] = "folder/text.txt";
char arry[30][30];
FILE *file;

file = fopen(fname, "r");
for(int x=0; x<30; x++){
    for(int i=0; i<30; i++){
        arry[x][i] = fgetc(file);
    }
}

fclose(file);
for(int i=0; i<30; i++){
    printf("%s\n", arry[i]);
}
```

Most likely I have just made an obvious mistake, but I'm not able to find it. So please help.

Comment: See the title of your question is strange! You can't say `printf()` prints a 2d array. It can't.

Comment: Remember that strings in C are really called *null terminated* byte strings. That terminator is what turns an array of characters into a string.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That's not the problem, that just me failing at writing my own code. But, tes tjat would be a problem...

Comment: `char arry[30][31];` ... `for(int i=0; i<30; ++i) { arry[x][i] = fgetc(file); } ` ... `arry[x][30] = '\0';`

Comment: @Adrian The purpose of the code is unclear.

Comment: Or, even better: `char arry[30][31];` ... `fgets(arry[x], 30, file);`

Comment: `fgetc(file)` what do you want to achieve by doing this? post your full code for us to better understand

Comment: The format of the _file_ is unclear.  What exactly separates words?  Just a capital letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think strings in file are not null terminated. So you need to put null character at the last character of the array.

```
char arry[30][30]

for(int x=0; x<30; x++){
    for(int i=0; i<29; i++){  //You can write 29 characters + '\0'
        arry[x][i] = fgetc(file);
    }
    arry[x][29] = '\0';
}
for(int i=0; i<30; i++){
    printf("%s\n", arry[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! As Ray Hamel also  suggested, I made the arry [30][31] and added '\0'.